# Ruby On Rails how do I constrain my index between two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm converting one of my apps from PHP to rails 4 and I'm stuck on making my index view default to a constraint on the date and also accept a start and end date from the params for the constrain.

The query in my PHP reads like so:

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM EVENTS WHERE EVENT_DATE >= '$start' AND EVENT_DATE <= '$end' ORDER BY EVENT_DATE ASC "
```

So that is probably similar to what active record needs to give me in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Event.where('event_date >= ? and event_date <= ?', start_date, end_date).order('event_date ASC')
```

where start_date and end_date - are your dates, and Event - is your event model

Answer (score 1):

You can put `scope` in your model, most probably in `event.rb` .

```
  scope :between_dates , -> (start_date,end_date) { where("'EVENT_DATE' >= ? AND 'EVENT_DATE' <= ?", start_date,end_date).order("'EVENT_DATE' ASC") }
```

And then you can call something like this in your index controller

```
def index 
  @events = Event.between_dates(1.day.ago, 2.day.ago)
end
```

PS: the above method will generate the desire query.

Comment: I'm leaning towards this answer by a hair for the moment because it helps keep my controller smaller.

Comment: No problem, have a look. It it worth mentioning  that whenever you want to find what will be the generated sql, you can always use `explain` function like `Event.between_dates(1.day.ago, 2.day.ago).explain`